# How to decrease db attribute value over time with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm creating a credit-based application, where the user puts credit in his account and the credit decreases over time based on user's active services.

For example:

- User deposits U$ 30 in his account
- User accquires a service that costs U$ 60/month
- His credits will decrease over time, so in the second day of use, user's credit will be U$ 28 (U$ 30 - U$ 2 from the accquired service)
- User will be able to see his current balance any time

I realize that I can use cron jobs to decrease the account balance, but it's gonna make a lot of requests to database and I am sure there must be better ways to do that.

How can I do it?

Comment: Perhaps you could write a little model method to decrement this on a specific page instead. For example whenever the user wants to see his current balance, execute method to check and update credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is using a `column` and a `callback` e.g.

You will need to add a column say `last_deducted_on` as `date` then in the `show` action of `account_balance` you can have a `before_action` like

```
before_action :deduct_amount_if_applicable, only: :show

private

def deduct_amount_if_applicable
  if current_user.deduction_applicable?
    amt = (Date.today - account.last_deducted_on).to_i * amount_to_be_deducted
    account.update_attribute(:total, (account.total - amt))
    # update column with today's date
  end
end
```

Although it will work, I suggest to use scheduler as it is a scheduled job and needs to be done every day, there are ways to reduce queries e.g. using `update_all`, etc. depending on use case but still the better option. In case if you have transaction history and you show date of transaction, above method will piss of user if he will open his account days later and suddenly huge amount is deducted.

Comment: Great approach, that should work. I will try it and feedback soon.